# How to pass types to a functional component in react using redux connect

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

So basically i have the connect function with mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps with my functional component, but if i try to access the props typescript throws an error

```js
const Navbar: FC = ({ route, doChangeRoute }) => {
    //... code here bla bla 
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ routeReducer }: AppState) => {
    const { route } = routeReducer;
    return { route };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({ doChangeRoute }, dispatch);

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
)(Navbar);

// ERROR: Property 'route' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'.  TS2339
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the types when using connect to make TypeScript happy:

```
export default connect<StateType, ConnectProps, OwnProps>(
    mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps
)(Navbar)
```

Where:

`StateType` is the type of your state or just pass `{}` if you have no state.

`ConnectProps` is the type of the props connect will assign to your component

`OwnProps` is the type of the props expected by the component that do *not* come from connect